# Mobile Web using PHP Sessions Problem

Tags: php, session, mobile, doctype

I am enabling an existing platform written in PHP to be delivered via mobile web browser.  I am getting the "Cannot send Session Cache limiter - headers already sent" error.

First line of code is `<? php session_start(); ?>`  This is the line in question.

Since it is for delivery on a smart phone, we have the standard headers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
```

If I go to a flat `<html><head><body>` configuration, I can manage the sessions, but then of course I lose my phone enablization.

I am at a loss 3-4 hours of experimenting in.

Comment: Just to confirm: is the `session_start` line *literally* the first line of code in your source file?

Comment: Yes.  no spaces above it at all.

Comment: Then out of curiosity, why have you provided the static HTML in your question?  Sending the headers occurs before any text is sent.  And what do you mean by "If I got to a flat configuration..."?

Comment: I can pass the sessions without an issue in PHP delivered to a web browser with <html><head><body> format.  However when I try to pass variables through a mobile web browser (emulated and real device both) I get the error.

Comment: I have isolated it to the following call:    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

Comment: The type of client browser should not affect this, unless you have a very strange server configuration which is conditionally breaking things before PHP gets a chance to send the headers.

Comment: Oli, thanks for all of the input.  I took out the content-type call with a viewport call instead and it is working just fine.  I don't control the server and am working in an existing environment so there may be some global settings or server settings that are bombing it.

Answer (score 0):

Issue not in "mobile web", you just have to fix your error with headers. After `headers already sent` should be line, where headers sent.
Try to remove BOM symbol, try to use [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).
At least try to use search - `headers already sent` it's most frequently asked question in PHP.